# Write a linux script to find errors occurred in a log file during the last hour and send mail if errors found

Tags: bash, shell, logging, grep

I want to find errors which have occurred in log file during the last hour. This is because I plan to schedule the script every hour in cron. I want to search for multiple error patterns and want to send mail if any one of those error patterns have been found during the last hour. Can someone please help me?

#Script which I tried to write is below

```
#!/bin/bash

SUBJECT="Critical errors found on $HOSTNAME"
TO="abc@example.com"
FNAME="/var/log/log4j/test.log"
PATTERN1="StackOverflow"
PATTERN2="OutOfMemory"

if [ ! -f stack.txt ]; then
    touch stack.txt
fi

if [ ! -f comp_stack.txt ]; then
    touch comp_stack.txt
fi

#first 19 bytes of log entry represents date/timestamp
cat stack.txt > comp_stack.txt
first_date="$(head -c19 comp_stack.txt)"
echo "first date is $first_date"

tac "$FNAME" | grep -m 1 -i "$PATTERN1\|$PATTERN2"  > stack.txt

next_date="$(head -c19 stack.txt)"
echo "next date is $next_date"

if [ -s stack.txt ] && [ "$next_date" != "$first_date" ]; then
    echo "dates not equal and file exists"
    mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$TO" < stack.txt
fi
```

My script is creating 2 files stack.txt and comp_stack.txt if they don't exist.
It is supposed to search for pattern1 and pattern2 during last hour (I used "-m 1" to achieve this, but it gives me only 1 pattern in the output even if there are multiple patterns which match the error).
As I don't want the script to report same error multiple times, I am saving and comparing dates in my .txt files. So that error will be reported only if error timestamp is different from what was previously saved in the .txt file.
I used "tac" to search my log files from bottom to top as my log files are huge and I want to save time.

I am new to linux and scripting. Please help me write a working script.

Here is one line sample of my log file -

2020-09-01 01:27:16,500 | DEBUG | WebContainer : 17 | | | com.hertz.rates.common.utils.jdbc.RecordCallableStatement | DB Response: Activate/Cancel | 65 | READY | 2020-09-01 01:27:16,500 | DEBUG | WebContainer : 17 | | | com.hertz.rates.common.utils.jdbc.RecordCallableStatement | DB Response: Activate/Cancel | 65 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mail="abc@example.com"                    # email address
subj="Critical errors found on $HOSTNAME" # email subject
logf="/var/log/log4j/test.log"            # log file name
errs="StackOverflow|OutOfMemory"          # define errors to check
printf -v time '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:)T'         # get time template

check=$(grep "$time" "$logf" | grep "$errs" "$logf")
[[ $check ]] && mail -s "$subj" "$mail" <<< "$check"
```

Comment: Hi Ivan,
Thanks for replying. Can you please explain what time does the time template evaluate to. I got an error while running the printf command. Can you please explain the script?

Comment: it's `day.month hour:` you have to change it to meet your needs.

Comment: And could you update your question with an example of your log file?

Comment: Hi Ivan,
Apologies for the delay in reply
Here is a sample log file -

2020-09-01 01:27:16,500 | DEBUG | WebContainer : 17 |  |  | com.hertz.rates.common.utils.jdbc.RecordCallableStatement | DB Response:
Activate/Cancel | 65 | READY |
2020-09-01 01:27:16,500 | DEBUG | WebContainer : 17 |  |  | com.hertz.rates.common.utils.jdbc.RecordCallableStatement | DB Response:
Activate/Cancel | 65 | READY |

Comment: @Durga updated my answer with new time template according to this log.